# What is the proper way to test a rails api with token auth in acceptance specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rspec

I'm writing acceptance specs for a rails api. I was able to do this in requests specs but I want to build acceptance specs in order to use the rspec_api_documentation gem to generate documentation.

My request spec looks like this:

```
let(:headers) { { 'accept': 'application/json' } }
let(:user) { users(:jane) }

describe '#show' do
    let(:endpoint) { "/api/v1/users/#{user.username}" }

    context 'when authenticated' do
      let(:expected_response) { "{\"user\":#{user.to_builder.target!}}" }
      let(:headers) { { 'Authorization': token, 'accept': 'application/json' } }
      let(:token) do
        post '/api/v1/authenticate',
             params: { email: user.email, password: 'testpassword' },
             headers: { 'accept': 'application/json' }
        JSON.parse(response.body)['auth_token']
      end

      it 'I can get user info' do
        get endpoint, params: {}, headers: headers
        expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
        expect(response.body).to eq expected_response
      end
    end
end
```

So far I have this but it does not work because let variables are not accessible outside example groups.

```
RSpec.resource 'Users' do
  header 'Accept', 'application/json'
  header 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
  get '/api/v1/users/:id' do
    explanation 'First, get an auth token, then request user info'

    fixtures :users

    let(:auth_token) do
      client.post '/api/v1/authenticate',
                  params: { email: user.email, password: 'testpassword' },
                  headers: { 'accept': 'application/json' }
      JSON.parse(response_body)['auth_token']
    end
    let(:id) { user.id }
    let(:user) { users(:jane) }

    header 'Authorization', auth_token

    example_request 'Getting a specific user' do
      expect(response_body).to eq(user.to_json)
      expect(status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs of the gem](https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation#header):

> **header**
>
> This method takes the header name and value. The value can be a string or a symbol. If it is a symbol it will send the symbol, allowing you to let header values.

Based on this, I think you have to declare the header like this:

```
header 'Authorization', :auth_token
```

Have a look at the example in the docs right below the cited paragraph.